# Using Bing maps with Ionic 3

Tags: google-maps, ionic-framework, ionic3, bing-maps

I'm currently working on a project using Ionic 3 Framework for a mobile app, part of this app is to use maps and geolocation, so I was instructed to use Bing maps with this app.

Can I use Bing maps with Ionic 3? Are there any docs that can help me with using Bing maps with Ionic 3? For example in ionic dev docs there is good support documentation that can help with Google maps, is there any docs that can help me with using Bing maps with Ionic 3?

This is my first time building an app with Ionic Frameworks.

Your help is most appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a little example here.

Download it and see the code, maybe it helps you

[Bing Maps Fleet Tracker](https://github.com/Microsoft/Bing-Maps-Fleet-Tracker/blob/master/MobileClient/README.md)